# LM2576 simulation not working at datasheet frequency

Tags: analog, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice

I'm designing a buck converter with TI's LM2576. This is the functional block diagram of the IC, extracted from the [the official datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf)

[image]

Output node voltage will be a square wave, and inductor current will be a triangular wave. Both waveforms will have the same fundamental frequency, and I understand that this frequency should be equal to the 52 kHz of the internal oscillator used in the comparator.

However, when simulating in LTspice with the model provided by TI, I'm having output waveforms of approx 2 kHz fundamental frequency. Here is the circuit I'm simulating

[image]

I'm obtaining this output waveforms. With the readings of the cursors it's seen that the fundamental frequencies are around 2 kHz. A fourier analysis of the waveforms confirms this, and shows that at 52 kHz there is no signal energy, just noise.

[image]

[image]

Is there something wrong with the simulation? Or am I wrongly assuming that the fundamental frequency at the output is the oscillator frequency?

I need to know this frequency as it is needed for all the components value calculation. I found no application note or datasheet mentioning that these frequencies can be different.

Comment: 1) Your inductor is 4.2 mH while on the first sheet of the datasheet, they're using a 100 uH inductor. Can you explain why you are using 4.2 mH? 2) It is unclear what **diode model** you are using, my suggestion would be to use the model of a fast Schottky diode. 3) **Maybe** capacitor C1 doesn't have any **series resistance** and some DCDC converters cannot handle that and need the output capacitor to have a little bit of series resistance (ESR).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie has it right.  ESR of less than .030 ohms will cause instability as might the enormous inductor value.  Add some explicit ESR if it's not in your model, and use something like a 100 uH inductor instead of 4.2 mH.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both comments. You are right, changing the capacitor ESR fixed the problem. The value of 4.2 mH was left there because of some experimenting, the real value is around the 100 uH of the datasheet. If you could link some resources explaining more about this instability issue it would be great (I assume it's some kind of simulator instability, not a circuit one)

Comment: *I assume it's some kind of simulator instability, not a circuit one* For proper stability the ESR is needed, both in the real world and in the simulator. In a real world circuit there will always be some ESR as ideal (ESR less) capacitors do not exist. You will have to consult a textbook on the design of DCDC converters for an explanation as it is not that easy to explain. If I remeber correctly the ESR creates a zero in the loop transfer which is needed for a stable loop.

Comment: Try right-clicking the diode, cap, and inductor and choosing "Pick device." These give them better models with parasitic values, like ESR.